Not able to send emails to gmail.com domained emails from @gmail.com verified email addresses using the AWS SES "Send Test Email" feature
I have verified the email address hari@gmail.com on my SES (that has production access enabled). I verified it and now using the "Send test email" feature of the AWS SES, I tried sending multiple emails to shyam@gmail.com.
Issue:
I received a few of the emails after hours and a few of the emails were never received.
I am confused about this behavior. What is causing this?
